# For this function, what does "return Left" mean in the case of IO?

Tags: mongodb, haskell

In [Database.MongoDB.Query](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-2.1.1/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html), there is this function:

```
access :: MonadIO m => Pipe -> AccessMode -> Database -> Action m a -> m a
```

The documentation says this about the function:

> Run action against database on server at other end of pipe. Use access mode for any reads and writes. Return Left on connection failure or read/write failure.

- What does "return Left" mean here? I ask because `m` can be any monad (with a `MonadIO` instance). For instance, what does "return Left" mean if `m` is just the `IO` monad?
- Must `m` be the `Either` monad for me to be able to detect connection or read/write failure when using the `access` method?

Comment: The actual code simply throws exceptions in case of error - I'm guessing that "return Left" is just a typo or a remnant from a time when the return type was different. "return Left" is indeed completely nonsense when working with `IO` or `MonadIO m` (I suppose it makes sense if you had e.g. `IO (Either a b)` ). Furthermore, `Either` cannot be an instance of `MonadIO` so you can't even instantiate `m` with `Either`. Although, `MonadIO m => EitherT e m` has an instance, but even if you use this instantiation, you will never get `Left something` from `access` - it's type even guarantees this.

Comment: [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-1.1.0/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html) is an old version in which the return type is `m (Either Failure a)` - it does really seem like just a case of outdated documentation. (If it's important to you, you should contact the maintainer)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/issues)`s probably a good place to report that - or you could even make a pull request by clicking on the pencil icon [here](https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/blob/master/Database/MongoDB/Query.hs) to do the work for him.

Comment: @user2407038 That's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @user2407038 Write this into an answer please so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's a type. Return Left comes from an older version. If any errors happens then it just throws IO exceptions. We'll need to fix it.
I filed a bug for it. https://github.com/mongodb-haskell/mongodb/issues/67